# My file name is the same as my menu name. jquery takes the file name when I click the menu name

Tags: javascript, jquery

my file name is the same as my menu name.how jquery takes the file name when I click the menu name?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mySidenav > a').on('click', function () {
  var linkText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  $("#isi").load("./"(linkText),".html");

  $.get("./"(linkText),".html", function(data) {
     $("#isi").html(data);
  });
  console.log(linkText);
  return false;

 });
 });
```

Comment: $("#isi").load("./"(linkText),".html"); <-- syntax error. That is not how you do basic string concatenation.

Comment: then what is a good way for that?

Comment: JavaScript 101: `"a" + "b" + "c" + "d"`

Comment: thanks sir i'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySidenav > a').on('click', function () {
  var linkText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  $("#isi").load("./"+linkText+".html");

  $.get("./"+linkText+".html", function(data) {
    $("#isi").html(data);
  });
  console.log(linkText);
  return false;

  });
 });
```

Comment: You are missing a `+` in this line: `$("#isi").load("./"+linkText".html");`